# Multiple Buttons for one webView from different Controller

Tags: swift

Hello my aim is to use on webView in WebController from buttons which are in different controllers. The problem is that my code works on one Controller but not from other two, even though the code is the same.

webView:

```
var receivedUrl: URL!
@IBOutlet weak var showPage: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //let url = URL(string: "https://kbtu.edu.kz/en/kbtu-virtual-tour")
    //let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let request = URLRequest(url: receivedUrl)
    showPage.load(request)
```

firstViewController which works with web view:

```
 var urlToPass: URL!
@IBAction func passUrl(_ sender: UIButton) {
    urlToPass = URL(string: "https://kbtu.edu.kz/en/kbtu-virtual-tour")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "thirdSegue", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    guard let destination = segue.destination as? WebViewController else { return }
    destination.receivedUrl = urlToPass
}
```

second which doesn't work:

```
class AlumnuViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

var urlToPass: URL!
@IBAction func showWeb(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    urlToPass = URL(string: "https://kbtu.edu.kz/en/alumni-kbtu-en")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "fifthSegue", sender: nil)
    
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    
    guard let destination = segue.destination as? WebViewController else { return }
    destination.receivedUrl = urlToPass
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Have you tried to print `receivedUrl` in your `webView` when the segue is triggered by `AlumnuViewController`?

Comment: it says that I pass nil to receivedUrl in webViewController

Comment: try to move `urlToPass = URL(string: "https://kbtu.edu.kz/en/alumni-kbtu-en")` to your prepare for segue.

Comment: Thank you! the helped. But do you know why it opens twice? The webView opens to time for some reason

Comment: you probably connected the segue to the action rather than the viewController, than you call performSegue so it perform the segue twice

Comment: oh okay thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome. You can accept the answer if it helped. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You prepare the segue before you perform it but at that point `urlToPass` is still nil.

According to Apple Documentation:

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses
> override this method and use it to configure the new view controller prior to it being displayed

Moving your configuration logic inside `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`, rather than  `@IBAction func showWeb(_ sender: UIButton)` should solve the problem.